# changing view's background color on every click of a button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicolor

```
-(IBAction) changeColOnClick:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"[UIColor brownColor]",@"[UIColor blackColor]",@"[UI greenColor]",@"[UIColor redColor]", nil];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
    // ERROR::changebackground[1089:207] -[NSCFString CGColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x357c

    //label.text = [colors objectAtIndex:i]; //i is defined in the implementation
    i++;

    if(i==[colors count]-1)
    {
        i=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code like this. It will work

```
-(IBAction) changeColOnClick:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor brownColor],[UIColor blackColor],[UI greenColor],[UIColor redColor], nil];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
    //label.text = [colors objectAtIndex:i]; //i is defined in the implementation
    i++;

    if(i==[colors count]-1)
    {
        i=0;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is crashing because your saving strings into your array. Try to save to the actual colors into the array like so:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor brownColor], [UIColor blackColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor redColor], nil];

self.view.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
```

If this still doesn't work you might need to something like:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = ((UIColor *)[colors objectAtIndex:i]).CGColor;
```

Answer (score 2):

`@"[UIColor brownColor]"` in `array` are of type `NSString` not `UIColor`.

So `array` should be like this:

```
 NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor brownColor],[UIColor blackColor],[UI greenColor],[UIColor redColor], nil];
```

add single instance like this for `MutableArray`:

```
 [colors addObject:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

so on:

Answer (score 1):

you add your colors to array like string object. That is not right.
You shoud do like that:

```
[colors addObject:[UIColor blackColor]];
[colors addObject:[UIColor redColor]];
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

hey mate i just testing your code and you just set your method like this way :-

```
int i;
-(IBAction) changeColOnClick:(id)sender
{

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"redColor",@"blackColor",@"greenColor",@"redColor", nil];


    NSString *str =[colors objectAtIndex:i];
    i++;
   //DARK_BACKGROUNDNavigation=str;

    SEL blackSel = NSSelectorFromString(str);
    UIColor* tColor = nil;
    if ([UIColor respondsToSelector: blackSel])
        tColor  = [UIColor performSelector:blackSel];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:tColor];

    if(i==[colors count]-1){i=0;}
}
```

its working  happy coding:)

**DOWNLOAD THE DEMO OF IT**

http://www.sendspace.com/file/9e68jx

Answer (score 1):

You have taken objects in array as strings so it gives array. You have to take UIColor type obects..

```
    UIColor *color1 = [UIColor brownColor];
    UIColor *color2 = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIColor *color3 = [UIColor greenColor];
    UIColor *color4 = [UIColor redColor];
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:color1,color2,color3,color4, nil];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
```